# Unable to insert a valid json in hive, getting a MismatchedTokenException

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am getting MismatchedTokenException on executing query as below:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> INSERT INTO TABLE test_data
. . > VALUES ('s92bd2d2u922432c43', 'd93d2e03422f234',
. . > '{"Foo": "ABC","Bar": "20090101100000","Quux": {"QuuxId": 1234,"QuuxName": 
. . > "Sam it doen't matter"}}');

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:88 mismatched 
input 't' expecting ) near ''{"Foo": "ABC","Bar": "20090101100000","Quux": {"QuuxId": 
1234,"QuuxName": "Sam it doen'' in statement (state=42000,code=40000)
```

It seems due to extra **'** in sentence "Sam it **doen't** matter".. it's failing.

But this is a valid json. How this can be resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that extra `'` is terminating the string from Hive's perspective, so it doesn't matter if it's valid JSON because it doesn't get a chance to pass it along to whatever is going to parse the JSON.  You can escape the `'` from the Hive command parser using a `\` similar to:

```
select get_json_object('{"Test":"This isn\'t a test"}','$');
```

Comment: Thanks, was having a typo in string replace while pushing  data through jdbc. With escape, it's working fine.